# 'undefined method init for Mysql:Class'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been having problems with a MySQL Server installation that got messed up after a power outage.

#### Configuration

Intel i5 Mac running OS X 10.6.5
Ruby 1.9.2 installed
Rails 3.0.1 installed
MySQL Server (finally) installed and running
I completely reinstalled MySQL, which deleted the local development/test/production databases. So, I have run `create database development;` in MySQL to get the dev database ready for a migration.

#### Current Goal

- Run `rake db:migrate` to get my databases back again. (I cannot currently access my databases or Mysql at all from Rails.)

#### Error

Using the gem `'mysql', '2.8.1'` and run `rake db:migrate`, I get the error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method 'init' for Mysql:Class
```

Stack Trace:

```
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:30:in 'mysql_connection'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in 'new_connection'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:238:in 'checkout_new_connection'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:194:in 'block (2 levels) in checkout'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in 'loop'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in 'block in checkout'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in 'mon_synchronize'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:189:in 'checkout'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in 'connection'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:318:in 'retrieve_connection'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in 'retrieve_connection'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in 'connection'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:486:in 'initialize'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:433:in 'new'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:433:in 'up'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:415:in 'migrate'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:142:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in 'call'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in 'block in execute'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in 'each'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in 'execute'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in 'block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in 'mon_synchronize'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in 'invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in 'invoke'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in 'invoke_task'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in 'block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in 'each'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in 'block in top_level'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in 'standard_exception_handling'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in 'top_level'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in 'block in run'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in 'standard_exception_handling'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in 'run'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in '<top (required)>'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake:19:in 'load'
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake:19:in '<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking is right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129644/rails-3-mysql-problems).

Oluf Nielsen

Comment: Hi Oluf, I tried ruby-mysql and I got a `missing packet` error - I also tried mysql2 and I got a `library not loaded` error. Unfortunately none of the solutions there have worked so far.

Comment: Oluf, ruby-mysql didn't work by itself but I finally fixed the issue by finding a very recent commit of ruby-mysql that did the trick. I'll explain what I did in an answer tomorrow.

Comment: Oluf: how did you fix it? I'm tearing my hair out on this one.

Comment: Ended up using an old version of the mysql gem, 2.7. This seems to work fine, I'll stick with it until the issues with the new version have been ironed out.

Answer (score 4):

I have Rails 3.1-rc4, MySQL 5.5.15 (just upgraded), and Mac OS X Lion. My issue turned out to be that the mysql_api.bundle file was linked to the right libmysqlclient.18.dylib file, but it could not find the library:

```
otool -L ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle 
/Users/rowland/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle:
    /Users/rowland/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.9.1, current version 1.9.1)
    libmysqlclient.18.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

At runtime the library is not found. My first attempt to fix this was to add an LC_RPATH command, but that was not enough (perhaps because it was at the end of the list). Instead I directly changed the library link with:

```
install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180\@rails-3.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
```

Now otool shows me:

```
otool -L ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180\@rails-3.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle 
/Users/rowland/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails-3.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle:
    /Users/rowland/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.9.1, current version 1.9.1)
    /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

and it is all happy again. This only works on Mac OS X though.

Comment: thanks!!! this worked for me :), obviously had to change the gemset to reflect my version 1.8.7-p352@rails2 though

Answer (score 2):

This line helped me to get rid of the error above. On Mac OS X 10.7. Lion

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 1):

no other solution worked for me but:

```
brew install mysql-connector-c

sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

[ruby mysql with native extensions on mac osx](http://www.codeinvain.com/blog/410/installing-ruby-mysql-with-native-extensions-on-mac-osx-64-bit/)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error trying to get a rails site working on CentOS using the mysql-2.8.1 gem. I could run the site just fine if I started it as root, but when I switched to my application user it would throw this error. It ended up being the permissions on the mysql directory structure. I ran a `chmod -R 755` on the mysql directory and restarted my rails server and the error went away. The error is a little vague and seems to cover everything when the driver is connecting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on ubuntu

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib
ldconfig
```

I just put this at the bottom of `/etc/profile` and for any new logins things work fine. You can quickly test it without logging in again by doing this

```
source /etc/profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Shaun's answer, which I was able to use:

My setup is OS X Lion + apache + passenger + mysql installed via Homebrew.  When I run "rails server" I have to have a DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable set, but I couldn't figure out how to set it in apache. I had to do this:

```
cd /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib `brew --prefix mysql`/lib/libmysqlclient_r.18.dylib mysql_api.bundle
```

Same answer, just specific to Homebrew installation, and my gems were not in ~/.rvm/gems like his were.

Answer (score 0):

I get same error, but i have replace gem from 'mysql' to 'mysql2' and its works for me
So i share with you people if any one have still get same error