# MySQL gem problem - undefined method `init' for Mysql:Class

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['undefined method init for Mysql:Class'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545701/undefined-method-init-for-mysqlclass)

This is part of an ongoing problem I've had after upgrading to Snow Leopard.

I've reinstalled MySQL, Ruby and Rails. Now when I run rails server and go to localhost:3000 I get:

```
undefined method `init' for Mysql:Class
```

I'm running
**Ruby 1.8.7

Rails 3.0.3

MySQL 5.5.8**

I have gem 'mysql' in my GemFile.

I can't figure out the problem. Can somebody help?

Comment: Did you ever solve this without switching to ruby-mysql gem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove and then reinstall the mysql gem with the new ruby native extensions bindings.

Try this command with a sudo.

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Comment: Have tried this and unfortunately still get "undefined method `init' for Mysql:Class" when I run the rails server